# How to show that a measurable function on $R^d$ can be approximated by step functions?

Tags: real-analysis, approximation

In Stein's Book: **Real Analysis**, Theorem 4.3 says that any measurable function $f$ on $R^d$ can be approximated by step functions. But the proof provided there only show that when $f=\chi_E$, with $m(E)<+\infty$ can be approximated by step function $\psi_k$ (a.e.).
How to complete the argument?

Comment: do you know how to do it for $\mathbb{R}$? can you just take some blocks of $E$ and glue them together?

Comment: It sames that the argument must depended on Egonov's Theorem, but how to, I don't know.

Comment: why can't you chop $\mathbb{R}^n$ into blocks $E_1,E_2,...$ such that $m(E_i)<\infty$. then find a sequence of step function of each  one of them. then you glue the functions together?

Comment: Since the convergence may depended on $x$, thus you can't taken an subsequence of step function for "every x".

Comment: I don't get what you mean. maybe my own understading is wrong. you can get sum of indicator functions from what you have done. then any positive measurable functions can be approximated by sum of indicator functions. For a general measurable function, you split a general measurable function into its positive and negative part

Comment: See also:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362406/can-a-measurable-function-in-rd-be-approximated-by-step-function

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach.

1. Let $E$ be a measurable set, and $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists a step function $\psi$ s.t. $m\left(\big\{\,x\,\big\vert\,\psi(x)\neq\chi_E(x)\big\}\right)\le\epsilon$.
2. Let $\phi$ be a simple function and $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists a step function $\psi$ s.t. $m\left(\big\{\,x\,\big\vert\,\psi(x)\neq\phi(x)\big\}\right)\le\epsilon$.
3. Let $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ be two sequences of functions such that $f_n\to f$ as $n\to\infty$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty m_*\big(\big\{\,x\,\big\vert\,g_n(x)\neq f_n(x)\,\}\big)<+\infty$. Then $g_n\to g$ a.e. (Hint: it's easier if you apply the Borel–Cantelli lemma in Stein, RA, Chapter 1, Exercise 16)
4. Note that $f$ could be pointwise approximated by simple functions, then apply 2,3.

Comment: 2 is obvious: take $\psi=\phi$. What do you want to say exactly in 2?

Comment: @Groups Edited, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share my answer, it is a litter long, and I will just guide the proof:

> **step 1:** For $f=\chi_E$, with $m(E)<\infty$, see Stein's Book Thm4.3: there exist step function $\phi_k\to\chi_E$ a.e. in $R^d$;
>
> **step 2:**. For general simple function $\psi=\sum_{l=1}^n a_l\chi_{E_{l}}(x)$ (note that by definition $m(E_l)<\infty$, $\forall l$), there exists step function $\phi_{k}$, such that $\phi_{k}\to\psi$ a.e. in $R^d$;
>
> **step 3:** By Stein's book Thm4.2, for measurable function $f$ on $R^d$, there exists simple function $\psi_k\to f$ point-wise in $R^d$. Thus, by step 2. there exist step function $ \phi_{k,j}\to\psi_k$, $\forall k$. For each $k$, we can select a cubic $Q_k$ centered at the origin with length of side k.  We see that $\phi_{k,j}\chi_{Q_k}\to\psi_k$,$\forall k$, so we can replace $\phi_{k,j}$ by $\phi_{k,j}\chi_{Q_k}$.
>
> **step 4:** Apply Egorov's Thm on $Q_k$ to select $J(k)$, such that $$|\psi_k-\phi_{k,J(k)}|<\frac{1}{k},\quad\forall x\in A_k.$$
>   where $A_k$ is contained in the union of $ Q_k \text{and }\cup_{l=1}^{\infty} E_l$ with $ m(Q_k\cup\cup_{l=1}^{\infty} E_l\backslash A_k)<\frac{1}{2^k}$.
>
> **step 5:** Let $E=\limsup_{k=1}^\infty ((Q_k\cup\cup_{l=1}^{\infty} E_l\backslash A_k)$, prove that $m(E)=0$, and $\phi_{k,J(k)}\to f$ a.e. in $E^c$.

Answer (score 1):

I am just reading this part, and Google sent me here.
This is what I guess to be closer to Stein's intention.
Use Theorem 4.2 (that there is a sequence of simple functions that pointwise $\to f$) to find
$$
\phi_k(x) = \sum _{l=1} ^{L_k} \alpha _{k,l} \mathbf{1} _{E_{k,l}}
$$
Here, $E_{k,l}$ measurable, and $\phi_k \to f$ pointwise.
By Thm.3.4 (iv), there are disjoint $Q_{k,l,s}$ so that
$$
m \big( E_{k,l} \Delta (\cup _{s=1} ^{S_{k,l}} Q_{k,l,s}) \big)
\leq 2^{-k} \epsilon L_k^{-1}
$$
Define
$$
\psi_k
=\sum_{l=1} ^{L_k} \alpha _{k,l} \sum _{s=1} ^{S_{k,l}} \mathbf{1} _{Q_{k,l,s}}
$$
We see that
$$
\sum_{k=1} ^{\infty} \sum_{l=1} ^{L_k}
m \big( E_{k,l} \Delta (\cup _{s=1} ^{S_{k,l}} Q_{k,l,s}) \big)
\leq \epsilon
$$
by a similar argument for Borel-Cantelli lemma, the set on which convergence fails is a null set:
$$
\cap_{N=1} ^{\infty} \cup_{k=N} ^{\infty} \cup_{k=1} ^{L_k}
m \big( E_{k,l} \Delta (\cup _{s=1} ^{S_{k,l}} Q_{k,l,s}) \big)
\leq \epsilon
$$